# How to dynamically change angular service implementation?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm new to Angular2 and and I have two services `DefaultService` And `SpecialService` that shoud be used alternatively according to a component state 
I don't know if I can Inject into my component a singleton `GeneralService` that somehow behave like  `DefaultService` or `SpecialService` by changing its implementation.

I have another idea to inject both services in `generalService` and delegate thier methods to the appropriate service.

thanks to tell me how can I implement the first  Idea if doable, or suggest me anothers.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
   templateUrl : './content.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent  { 
constructor(generalService : GenralService,injector : Injectot){}
@ViewChild(MySon)
    private mySon : MySon;
    state : State;

    onChangeState(newState : State):void{
        if(state = special)
        //this.generalService = this.injector.get('SpecialService');
        myson.updateplease();
    }
}
```

Assume `SpecialService` and `DefaultService` extends `GeneralService`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleaner way would be to use an `interface`, so you will get intellisense! :)

```js
export interface IYourService {
  func1: (source: string, subString: string) => boolean;
  func2: () => void;
  func3: () => string;
}

@Injectable()
export class SuperService implements IYourService {
  public func1(source: string, subString: string): boolean {
    return true;
  }

  public func2(): void {
    console.log('SuperService: func2();');
  }

  public func3(): string {
    return "SuperService";
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class SpecialService implements IYourService {
  public func1(source: string, subString: string): boolean {
    return false;
  }

  public func2(): void {
    console.log('SpecialService: func2();');
  }

  public func3(): string {
    return "SpecialService";
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class GeneralService {

  public state = 'SuperService';

  constructor (
    private _superService: SuperService,
    private _specialService: SpecialService
  ) {}

  public get instance(): IYourService {
    if (this.state == 'SuperService') return this._superService;
    else return this._specialService;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2 (click)="switchService()">Hello {{name}} - active service: {{ this._generalService.state }} - click me to switch it!</h2>
      <button (click)="labelFunc1.innerHTML = _generalService.instance.func1()">func1</button>
      <label #labelFunc1></label>
      <br />
      <button (click)="_generalService.instance.func2()">func1</button>
      <br />
      <button (click)="labelFunc3.innerHTML = _generalService.instance.func3()">func1</button>
      <label #labelFunc3></label>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor(private _generalService: GeneralService) {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  private switchService() {
    if (this._generalService.state == 'SuperService') {
      this._generalService.state = 'SpecialService';
    }
    else this._generalService.state = 'SuperService';
  }
}
```

live demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/OM5nnAR0kzSeV24vKqL5?p=preview

Comment: hey looking to the plnkr it seems good, I didn't yet see the code well. thanks @mxii you're phantastic :)

Answer (score 3):

Your first idea is totally possible (if I understood it correctly). The idea would be to create `GeneralService` as an interface and then create two services that inherit from this interface and implement its function. Then, via the `injector`, you get a reference to the one you want.

Have a look at this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/rjghCDkc5jUjp1SSpjDK

Just change the `false` to `true` in here:

```
if (false)
{
  this.service = this.injector.get(SpecialService);
}
else
{
  this.service = this.injector.get(DefaultService);
}
```

To see that the logged value in the "console" changes. I put the initialization in `ngOnInit` but you could do it everywhere you want ;-)