# Angular DI (injector.get(FooService))

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection

I have just started reading some code from somewhere else and I have to understand it. I have read a lot in Angular website and some other coding related websites but I have not undersoot the following section yet and need your help.

```
export class AppComponent {
  w: FooService;
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    if (environment.production) {
      this.w = this.injector.get(FooService);
    }
  }
}
```

I do not understand why the developer has injected the FooService in such a way, and why didn't he implemented the injection like bellow:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(w: FooService) {
  }
}
```

And finally, would you please explain the main goal of `this.injector.get()`?

Comment: Because he is trying to have a conditional injection. He is injecting that service only if the environment is production. Maybe he is intended to use seperate services for separate environments which is really unnecessary but we can't really say that unless we know the full picture. Usually we have different application properties for different environments not the different services entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Injector can be used to dynamicaly(programaticaly) register or load a service.

Check the following example from official documentation

[Angular Injection Token doc](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken#plain-injectiontoken)

Also another example of how to manualy register and inject a service in a Test  again from official documentation

[Angular Manually Inject Service](https://angular.io/api/core/inject#usage-notes)

There is also another answer in SO with a specific use case for injector. An Angular Service that has 2 different implementations and some component that uses that service must choose dynamically an implementation for that service. This would be a good example to understand conditional injection that is reffered from
**Beshambher Chaukhwan** in comments.

[another relevant answer in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42699317/7237884)